# Funding Source?

Tags: plot-explanation, nikita

I've started watching [Nikita](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1592154/) (2010-TV). It seems Nikita is quite able to afford expensive spur of the moment things, to include travel and tech. **What is her funding source?** To this point in the series, she's just able to come up with the money. It doesn't state whether she has the money already or if she has a benefactor, or if she has some other means for obtaining what she needs to carry on her war with Division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember vaguely an episode where this point been explained (briefly). (After a bit of searching it was s01e16 “Echoes” but I can't find anything online about this point). So as far as remember, **she got a lot of money/counterfeit money from a banker was involved in a shady businesses she was suppose to assassinate him (while she was working at division) but didn't**. Also, **(Spoilers)** the focus of this subplot was that he owns the loft the she "operate" from and it was how a certain character tracked her.